# Not getting String value while while navigating to next Jsp page

Tags: javascript, ajax, scriptlet

I am trying here to send the string with the url while navigating to next page. I am successfully navigating but i am not getting the string value in my next page. Here is my code:

```
var u = 'paymentweb.jsp?uid=<%=uid%>';
                    alert(u);
                    window.location.href = u;
```

But in next page i am not getting the string value.Next page:

```
<%String n=(String)request.getAttribute("uid");%>
<%System.out.println(n);%>
```

Comment: The url has "uid" and the next page has "id"

Comment: Sorry.I edited still i am not getting